# F# refuses to determine type based on multiple constraints

Tags: list, types, f#

I've tried everything to get the compiler to listen. However, it refuses to understand. I'm trying to compare the color values of each element and if they are the same return true otherwise return false.

I've placed the constraints of what I want and it still can't determine the type.

```
let all_same_color cs =
  let mutable d=true
  let (col:Color) = card_color (cs.Head:Card)
  for i in cs do
    let col=card_color i
    if not (col = col) then
      printfn "Black"
      d<-false
    else
      d<-d
    printfn "Val %b" d
  d
```

I expect it to return true if colors match or false if they don't.

It errors at this line constantly:

```
let (col:Color) = card_color (cs.Head:Card)

 Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this programpoint to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.
```

Answer (score 5):

What the compiler is objecting to is the `cs.Head` expression, because it can't tell from that expression what the type of `cs` is. It could be a list of `Card`s, but it could also be any other class with a `Head` member: *at that point in the code*, F# can't tell what `cs` is. (Later when you do `for i in cs do ... card_color i`, that would be enough to identify the type of `cs`, but F#'s compiler is a single-pass compiler, so when it encounters `cs.Head` it does not yet have any other type hints about the type of `cs`.)

Define the type of `cs` in your function definition like so:

```
let all_same_color (cs : Card list) =
    // ...
```

and that will be enough. Or you could also replace `cs.Head` with `List.head cs` and that would *also* be enough to let the F# compiler figure out the type of `cs`:

```
let col = card_color (List.head cs)
```

And you'll note that now, there's no need to specify that `List.head cs` is a `Card`, or that `col` is a `Color`, because the function signature of `card_color` allowed F# to figure all that out.

By the way, there's an even easier way to determine whether your list of cards is all the same color, by using `List.map` and `List.distinct`:

```
let allSameColor cs =
    let distinctColors = cs |> List.map card_color |> List.distinct
    List.length distinctColors = 1
```

Two lines (which could even have been one line easily enough, but I figured writing it on two lines would make it simpler) that do the same thing as your original `all_same_color` function (and note that I used camelCase in my function name, because camelCase is the usual convention for F# function names). The only difference is that your function has side effects (printing either "Black" or "Val: (something)") while I've deliberately written a "pure", side-effect-free, function. It's good practice for each function to do only one thing: *either* return a value ***or*** have a side effect, but not both.